# Rails linking object to its category page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have an article model that has a title, body, author and category fields. All of the articles are grouped by their category which means i have 6 pages like "news", "bulletin" "sport" etc.

How could I link to an articles category page from its show page?

articlesController.rb

```
def news
      @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7).where(category: "News")
    end
```

rake routes & routes.rb

```
    news        /news(.:format)                                   articles#new

match '/news', controller: "articles", action: "news"
```

link

```
<b><%= link_to @article.category, @article.category_path?? %></b>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear WHAT EXACTLY you're asking. You want to link to what exactly? To a page that lists all the articles in the clicked category, or to the page where the category itself is shown (or can be edited). Your link_to code itself looks okay to me... btw: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Hi Vapire, I have reworded the question a bit, But i would like to link to the articles category page which lists all of the articles under that category. So in an article view i can go @article.category -> ("News") to show its category but i would like to then link to the news_path, but do this dynamically as there are a few categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With rails 2

```
#routes.rb
map.news       'news',     :controller => "Articles", :action => "news"
map.bulletin   'bulletin', :controller => "Articles", :action => "bulletin"
```

This will give your `news_path` or `bulletin_path`. In a particular function, you can load the `article_category` as well as all its articles.

Make a helper method `category_path` like below

```
def category_path(article)
    return eval("#{article.category.downcase}_path")
end
```

and links like

```
<%= link_to @article.category, category_path(@article) %>
```

Comment: Samiron thats great ty!, i tried to do something similar in the view but didnt think to give it a helper method, thans again!

Comment: As the solution worked for you, i will clean up my assumptions from the answer.